# When perform a search and no data found, we click reset button and get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". Any ideas why?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

We enter text into a search box, click the search button.

If data found and you click the reset button, you are gracefully returned to search screen.

If no data found and you click the reset button, the app breaks with the following error message:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

This error points to this line:

```
Dim getAll As CheckBox = DirectCast(gridview1.HeaderRow _
 .Cells(0).FindControl("getAll"), CheckBox)
```

This is the markup:

```
<HeaderTemplate>
 <asp:CheckBox ID="getAll" runat="server" onclick="getAllOf(this);CheckBox_getAll();" />
</HeaderTemplate>
```

The reset button from codebehind:

```
Protected Sub btnReset_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnReset.Click
    ' Simple clean up text to return the Gridview to it's default state
    searchBox.Text = ""
    SearchString = ""
    BindData()
End Sub
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

This is one of our most visible apps

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Does gridview1.HeaderRow exist when no data found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting [`GridView.ShowHeaderWhenEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.showheaderwhenempty.aspx) to true.

It sounds like, when your data control is empty, your header is not being displayed.  Thus, your code tries to access the header row, and throws an error because the object hasn't been initialized.

---

That, or you could just guard against the possibility that the HeaderRow is not there:

```
Dim getAll As CheckBox

If gridview1.HeaderRow IsNot Nothing Then
    getAll = DirectCast(gridview1.HeaderRow.Cells(0).FindControl("getAll"), CheckBox)
End If
```